# ¿Como puedo hacer cambio de divisas en PHP?

Tags: php, web, api

Estoy intentando adaptar la api de Google para que realize el cambio de moneda, pero al parecer ya no ofrecen ese servicio. Ahora estoy intentando hacer scraping para obtener el valor actual de la divisa, pero no entiendo mucho de eso, alguien tiene alguna idea? ya que este codigo no me funciona

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.banrep.gov.co/es/trm'); //Convierte la información de la URL en cadena
preg_match('/<b>(.*)<\/b/i',$html,$contenido);
echo $contenido[1];
```

Comment: Creo que algo como la api de fixer.io te puede servir

Comment: ¿No hay un servicio gratuito? Por lo que veo fixer.oi aunque tiene un servicio gratuito es muy limitado.

Comment: Mira florianv/exchanger y florianv/swap